# How to bring my javascript pop up to front?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am opening a pop up using javascript code as follows

```
var newwin = window.open('https://www.google.com', 'myPopup', 'height=100, width=100');
```

I want to always keep this pop up front to all my applications all the time, even If I open new browser window. How can I do that in Javascript/Jquery ?

Comment: You and every other annoying spammer/advertiser.

Comment: No, My application needs to be infront of all the application. That is my customer requirement. And those are not advertisements or spams

Comment: Unfortunately, browsers can't tell the difference.

Answer (score 1):

By default this will open in front of the current window. That is the most you can do.

Comment: I also want to bring that window to front if I click the main browser tab. generally after clicking other windows it's getting back to that window.

Comment: newwin.focus() should accomplish that - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.focus